# How to change image size in jupyter markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

works to load an image in a jupyter markdown cell

How can I adjust the image size?

![NN](./img/NN.png, width=100, height=100) doesn’t work

Answer (score 3):

Image control in Jupyter markdown is possible but the image needs to be preceded by "attachment" or it doesn't display.
What you have:

```
    ![NN](./img/NN.png)

    ![NN] <img src="attachment:NN.png" width="400">
```